# Jquerymobile - button to expand / collapse all

Tags: javascript, button, jquery-mobile

I try to do in one button function to expand or collapse whole list. 
I found this website [Filterable Opens Matching Collapsibles](https://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/04/25/filterable-opens-matching-collapsibles/comment-page-1/#comment-379), but I want do this in one button. 
I try something like this:

```
<script>
      $(document).on("pagecreate", "#punktyKontrolne", function () {
          $(document).on("click", ".collapseExpand", function(){
              if ($('#listviewContent').hasClass("ui-collapsible-collapsed")){
                $('#listviewContent [data-role="collapsible"]').collapsible("option", "collapsed", false);
              }
              else {
                var collapseAll = this.id == "ZwinRozwinWszystko";
                $('#listviewContent [data-role="collapsible"]').collapsible("option", "collapsed", collapseAll);
              }

          });
      });
    </script>
```

But it not's working. Only works collapse (else in code).

Thank's for help.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote that article you linked.

It depends on your exact requirements. **Omar** gave a nice response at that website that will expand all if any are collapsed, otherwise it will collapse all:

```
$(document).on("click", ".collapseExpand", function(){
    var collapseAll = $('#filterList [data-role="collapsible"] .ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed').length > 0 ? "expand" : "collapse";
    $('#filterList [data-role="collapsible"]').collapsible(collapseAll);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/3zzuxdfy/)**

If on the other hand you just want to do the opposite action of the last time you clicked the button regardless of how many items are currently expanded/collapsed, you can save the previous state to a data-attribute:

```
$(document).on("click", ".collapseExpand", function(){
    var collapseAll = $(this).data("expand") == false ;
    $('#filterList [data-role="collapsible"]').collapsible("option", "collapsed", collapseAll);
    $(this).data("expand", collapseAll ? false : true);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/3zzuxdfy/1/)**

Finally, if you want all collapsed items to expand and all expanded items to collapse, in other words, each item flips its current expanded state:

```
$(document).on("click", ".collapseExpand", function(){
    $('#filterList [data-role="collapsible"]').each(function(idx){
        $(this).collapsible("option", "collapsed", $(this).find('.ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed').length > 0 ? false : true);
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/3zzuxdfy/3/)**